# Updating Nifi Sensitive properties from API

Tags: apache-nifi, apache-nifi-registry

We are developing CI-CD for Nifi using Nifi registry & Azure Devops. We want it to be fully automated and are blocked on one issue. In our processors, we are using sensitive properties like passwords, etc. How can we update them from rest API or nipyapi module ?

Is it supported or what is the recommended way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sensitive properties setup is straightforward like any other property setup.

Sample snippet, using nipyapi, to update sensitive properties in GetTwitter processor.

```
# Custom method to return all processors in a process group by using group name; 
# Equivalent to nipyapi.canvas.list_all_processors(pg_id='root') but accepts group name
def get_all_processors_in_group(processgroup_name, "name"):
    # ...
    # ...

def update():
    processors_list = get_all_processors_in_group(processgroup_name, "name")
    processor = ... # Get 'GetTwitter' processor

    props = processor.component.config.properties
    props["Consumer Key"] = "Random key"
    props["Consumer Secret"] = "Random secret" # Sensitive value
    props["Access Token"] = "Random token"
    props["Access Token Secret"] = "Random token secret" # Sensitive value

    config = processor.component.config
    config.properties = props

    nipyapi.canvas.update_processor(processor, config)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a sensitive property using the UI, API, or command-line tool like NiFi CLI or NiPyAPI the same way you would set any other property. If you have secured your NiFi instance with TLS, all calls between your script and NiFi will be encrypted. You can issue a custom client certificate for the script to use to authenticate, or use Kerberos/SPNEGO if you've configured it.